# RF/Selenium2 Find an element "p" but don't have an ID

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm learning to use Robot Framework and Selenium2. I have to make some test on a website. But I have a problem. ^^

I'm doing test on logging. When I failed to log, I'm supposed to have a message on the page. So I try to test that the correct message appears.

The code looks like that :

```
<div id="col1">
<h1 class="layer-hdr">Msg</h1>
<p class="serverError">Message that I try to test :D</p>
```

...

So my purpose is to test with "Element Text Should Be" that my p is there and with the good msg.

I tried :

```
Login Should Have Failed
    Element Text Should Be  p.serverError   ${ERROR MSG}
```

But doesn't work :( 
Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Element Text Should Be    css=p.serverError    ${ERROR MSG}
```

Assuming that the first element to match that CSS selector is the element you want.

```
Element Text Should Be    css=#col1 p.serverError    ${ERROR MSG}
```

Might be better.

Check out http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html and especially the locating elements part.

Comment: Okay, i will try this. I found the site after too... But to be honest,  I'm even more confused now :p

Thanks for the answer